# Python - Zip Function and Filter - Pairwise Operations

Tags: python-3.x, filter, zip, pairwise

I find the below piece of code a bit confusing.

```
l1 = ['left', 'up', 'front']
l2 = ['right', 'down', 'back']

opposites=filter(lambda word: len(word[0]) > 3 and len(word[1]) >3,zip(l1,l2))
```

The above code is supposed to get words from the two lists that have a length of at least 3 letters and add them to a list (opposites) using filter and zip function.

I do not understand why we have word[0] and word[1]..."word" here to me is 1 list and we get the first two elements or something...

I do not have much experience with using these functions together but could somebody explain to me this part I n more detail...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, zip creates a list of pairs.

```py
l1 = ['left', 'up', 'front']
l2 = ['right', 'down', 'back']
assert list(zip(l1,l2)) == [('left', 'right'), ('up', 'down'), ('front', 'back')]
```

This list gets passed to the `filter` function.
The `word` as a lambda argument is confusing here as it represents a tuple (pair) of two strings.

So getting `word[0]` and `word[1]` gives you the first and the second word respectively from a pair.

More information about the zip function can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).